# Exceptions with calling web service using IP

Tags: android, service

when I call web service from my machine using 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1 , I got exception. But if I give the public IP, it works fine. Why it is happening?

And also, If I use my public IP, I can't access web service. But If I put the same code in another machine, and call that web service using the IP address of that machine, It works fine.

```
 //working fine

 url = new URL("http://192.168.50.122/NewsLetter/subscribing.php?register="+xmlString);

 //got Exception
 url = new URL("http://localhost/NewsLetter/subscribing.php?register="+xmlString);

//got Exception
 url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/NewsLetter/subscribing.php?register="+xmlString);

 //got Exception with my public IP - 192.168.50.117
 url = new URL("http://192.168.50.117/NewsLetter/subscribing.php?register="+xmlString);
```

Please help me... I was trying a lot, but could not solve it.

Thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as localhost is concerned, read the following link if you're using an emulator...

**Referring to localhost from the emulated environment**

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

I'm not sure about your other issues, however.

Comment: This is probably it.  If using the special alias for the host loopback interface doesn't work, it would be worth checking that the service on the development machine can be accessed from a web browser or whatever running on that machine (natively on the machine, not within the android emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue. We'll need a lot more info to even begin to help